# Joins with two tables conditionally based on the value of ONE column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables to manage purchase and issues of items.

item Table

```
+---------+-----------+
| item_id | item_name |
+---------+-----------+
|     500 | A4        |
|     501 | A5        |
|     502 | B5        |
|     503 | B4        |
|     504 | A3        |
+---------+-----------+
```

supplier Table

```
+-------------+---------------+
| sup_id      | supplier_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 | ABC Suppliers |
|           2 | DEF Suppliers |
|           3 | GHI Suppliers |
+-------------+---------------+
```

officer Table

```
+------------+--------------+
| officer_id | officer_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Jhon         |
|          2 | William      |
|          3 | Ken          |
|          4 | Robert       |
+------------+--------------+
```

purchase / issue table

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+------------+-----+-------------+
| update_id | bill_no | sup_id  | item_id |    date    | qty |    type     |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+------------+-----+-------------+
|      1000 |      10 |       1 |     500 | 2018-11-01 |  50 | purchase    |
|      1001 |      40 |       1 |     500 | 2018-11-02 |  25 | purchase    |
|      1002 |      32 |       2 |     500 | 2018-11-04 |  10 | issue       |
|      1003 |      25 |       3 |     500 | 2018-11-05 |  12 | issue       |
|      1004 |      14 |       1 |     500 | 2018-11-08 |  22 | purchase    |
|      1005 |      55 |       2 |     501 | 2018-11-09 |  10 | purchase    |
|      1006 |      30 |       2 |     502 | 2018-11-10 |  40 | purchase    |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+------------+-----+-------------+
```

02) purchase / issue table holds the purchase details and issue details by mentioning the "type" at the end of table.

03) I need to get the following output.

```
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+-----+------------+
| item_name | supplier_name / officer_name |    date    | qty |type        |
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+-----+------------+
| A4        | ABC Suppliers                | 2018-11-01 |  50 | purchase   |
| A4        | ABC Suppliers                | 2018-11-02 |  25 | purchase   |
| A4        | William                      | 2018-11-04 |  10 | issue      |
| A4        | Ken                          | 2018-11-05 |  12 | issue      |
| A4        | ABC Suppliers                | 2018-11-08 |  22 | purchase   |
| A5        | DEF Suppliers                | 2018-11-09 |  10 | purchase   |
| B5        | DEF Suppliers                | 2018-11-10 |  40 | purchase   |
+-----------+------------------------------+------------+-----+------------+
```

03) I used the following query

```
select item.item_name, 
       supplier.supplier_name, 
       purchase.date, 
       purchase.qty, 
       purchase.type 
from purchase 
join item on item.item_id = purchase.item_id
where supplier.sup_id in (select sup_id from supplier)
```

04) But I did't get the desired output. I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: How is officer related to supplier? Is it correct that issue rows join to officer and other rows join to supplier?

Comment: @Salman. when type= purchase, the purchase.sup_id = supplier.sup_id. when type=issue, the purchase.sup_id = officer.officer_id. Because, the purchases & issues are maintaining in the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SELECT` clause, you are referring to `supplier` table, without joining to that table. Now, it seems that you want to show `officer_name` when the purchase type is `issue`, else `supplier_name` when it is `purchase`.

We can do a `LEFT JOIN` to both the tables, and use `CASE .. WHEN` to determine the respective name.

I have removed the `WHERE .. IN` subquery, which does not seem to serve any purpose here.

```
select item.item_name, 
       CASE purchase.type 
         WHEN 'purchase' THEN supplier.supplier_name 
         WHEN 'issue' THEN officer.officer_name 
       END AS `supplier_name_officer_name`
       purchase.date, 
       purchase.qty, 
       purchase.type 
from purchase 
join item on item.item_id = purchase.item_id 
left join supplier on purchase.sup_id = supplier.sup_id 
left join officer on purchase.sup_id = officer.officer_id
```

Comment: But I need to join officer table when the type = "issue" in purchase table. There was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the supplier just as you did for the item. 
And I see no point in the where clause at all.